# Action bar in enyo

Tags: enyo

I want to create an action bar in enyo.js.Which will be common in all the pages of my application on the top of each page.Please help me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use onyx.Toolbar as my first component, then an enyo.Panels after that which holds the "pages" or views I want to give the user.  Then only the panel viewport changes and the toolbar is always there.